# Access denied on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, webforms

I converted an ASP.NET WebForms project from a Web Site to Web Application.  To use the Microsoft.Data.SQLClient we must have Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll copied into the Bin directory. I have added it to the project as a "file" and set the copy property to "Copy Newer". When I run the web application, I get the following error Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).   I am running a debug session in Visual Studio 2019 in local installation of IIS.

I have confirmed that Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll is in the Bin folder. I have set Bin folder permissions for all IUSR type accounts.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues?q=is:issue+access+denied+iis If none of them helps, open a new issue there.

Comment: 1)could you try reinstalling the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nuget package2)are you running any antivirus software?3)try to add the admin user as custom account in the iis application pool identity4)check if the dll file is not locked by using properties. if nothing works you could try to use procmon tool to check the access denied error for the dll